# cout doesn't work after cin in vs2012

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
int age;
int ageTotal = 0;
int numberOfPeopleEntered = 0;
cout << "Enter the age of the first person or enter -1 to quit" << endl;
cin >> age;

while (age != -1){
    ageTotal = age + ageTotal;
    numberOfPeopleEntered++;

    cout << "Enter the age of the next person or enter -1 to quit" << endl;
    cin >> age;
}

cout << "the number of people entered is: " << endl;
cout << "the average age is: " << endl;



getchar();
return 0; 
}
```

Hi all, I am new to c++ programming.
here, I am practicing c++ coding with visual studio 2012.
Here, the problem is that when I try debugging my code. The code can be built, but the cout code after the while loop cannot work. The debugger will just close the window  after I enter -1 for age. I don't know why. Also, if I delete my whole while loop code block, the cout still cannot work after cin >> age.

Comment: Please do **not** post links or images of your code. Copy (and format properly) it into the question instead.

Comment: The console window will close as soon as the program terminates.  If you have no statements delaying or stopping it, you won't see your output.

Comment: Also, you need to actually tell it what values you want it to output on lines 22 & 23.  As it is now, it won't actually output any numbers, just the text itself.

Comment: If you don't want the window to close automaticly in the end, you can run it with ctrl+F5. Also the line 22 and 23 should probably output something.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks for the guidance, I am new to the community. Ihave just edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

The `getchar()` is consument by the cin input and it does nothing.

Substitute getchar() for

```
char t;
cin>>t;
```

Answer (score 1):

The cout is executed, but the console is closed as the program ended.

To prevent this add

```
system("PAUSE")
```

before the `return 0;`, this way, the console will be in pause, and you will be able to read the output.

Answer (score 0):

You forget insert the variable with *number of people* and the *expression for compute the average age*. So you lines 22 and 23 should be

```
cout << "the number of people entered is: " << numberOfPeopleEntered << endl;
cout << "the average age is: " << (float) ageTotal / numberOfPeopleEntered << endl;
```

Comment: I also see that, but I thing is not the OPs problem.